# how to select and remove graphic (by rings array) in ArcGIS API for Javascript 3.x

Tags: javascript, esri, arcgis-js-api

I am using JSAPI 3.x.

I have graphic layer in Feature Layer and I want to select and remove graphic (by rings) one by one. How can I achieve that?

As of now when I select graphic, it select the whole graphic and .clear() or .remove() doesn't work.

[image]

Select and remove graphic based on these rings array 
[image]

Comment: do you need to save the data back into the server or just removing rings in the map is enough?

Comment: @BelowtheRadar, Yes i do need to save the data back to server. thanks so much for you answer. I will try and let you know how i go :)

Comment: Ok, there was an error in my answer. See the edit.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the `featureLayer` click event. In the callback I would create a temp polygon from each rings of the graphic clicked to find in which ring the map point falls in, then I'll remove it.

```
featureLayer.on("click", function(evt) {
   var graphic = evt.graphic;
   var mapPoint = evt.mapPoint;

   if (graphic.geometry.rings.length > 1) {
       graphic.geometry.rings.forEach(function(ring, ringIndex) {
           var tempPolygon = new Polygon(graphic.spatialReference).addRing(ring));
           if (tempPolygon.contains(mapPoint) {
              graphic.geometry.removeRing(ringIndex);
           }
       });
    }
});
```

Comment: hey Mate, that works, thanks. was wondering how can I remove multiple rings and make sure user can't remove if there's only one ring left. have tried `let addToArray = []; addToArray.push(tempPolygon)` but I only ever have one and newly clicked value.

Comment: Just test if there is more than 1 ring before the forEach loop

Comment: Hey Mate, It lets me select more than one rings but doesn't remove them.